# PHPBB nested template loops not working correctly

Tags: php, html, loops, templating, phpbb

I'm trying to wrap my head around PHPBB [templating](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Tutorial.Template_syntax) but it's not working like I want.

So this is what the HTML of my template looks like:

```html
<div id="invtabs">
                  <ul>
                   <!-- BEGIN TAB_LOOP -->
                        <li><a href="#invtabs-{TAB_LOOP.TAB_ID}">{TAB_LOOP.TAB_NAME}</a></li>
                    <!-- END TAB_LOOP -->
                </ul>
                <!-- BEGIN TAB_LOOP -->
                <div id="invtabs-{TAB_LOOP.TAB_ID}">
                     <!-- BEGIN ITEM_LOOP -->
                        <img src ="images/custom_avatars/item_thumbnails/{TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.ITEM_ID}.png" />
                     <!-- END ITEM_LOOP -->
                </div>
                  <!-- END TAB_LOOP -->
            </div>
```

As you can see, I have a nested loop in the HTML and I'm trying to have

```
<img src ="images/custom_avatars/item_thumbnails/{TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.ITEM_ID}.png" />
```

show up in the content () of each tab, however the result I'm getting is **each tab blank** and the content (img) only **showing up under the 8th tab**. "hair" here's a picture to demonstrate.

[image]

This is the relevant PHP.

```
 //SEND TAB-INFO TO TEMPLATE AND BUILD TABS.
foreach($avatar_layer_tabs as $tabs){
    $template->assign_block_vars('TAB_LOOP', array(
        'TAB_ID' => $tabs['tab_id'],
        'TAB_NAME' => $tabs['tab_name']
        ));
}

//LOOP THROUGH ITEMS -> CHECK FOR THUMBAIL
    foreach($users_items as $items){
        $template->assign_block_vars('TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP', array(
            'ITEM_ID' => $items['item_id'],
            'ITEM_TAB' => $items['main_tab']
            ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found the answer.
It was a silly mistake in my logic.

```
foreach($avatar_layer_tabs as $tabs){
    $template->assign_block_vars('TAB_LOOP', array(
        'TAB_ID' => $tabs['tab_id'],
        'TAB_NAME' => $tabs['tab_name']
        ));

    if($users_items){

    //LOOP THROUGH ITEMS -> CHECK FOR THUMBAIL
        foreach($users_items as $items){
            makeThumbnails();
            $template->assign_block_vars('TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP', array(
                'ITEM_ID' => $items['item_id'],
                'ITEM_TAB' => $items['main_tab']
                ));
        }
    } else {
        trigger_error('There was a problem, it looks like you have no items. Please contact an administrator.');
    }
}
```

I had the "item_loop" outside the "tab_loop" rather than inside, which made the item_loop attach to the last iteration of the tab_loop.